# How can I set TypeScript compiler options in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

There are a number of setting for TypeScript that would normally be specified in a tsconfig.json file.  For example, I would like to set the   ExperimentalDecorators value.

VS 2015 supports adding a tsconfig.json file which by default has this content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

However, attempting to build causes this error: "Unable to get value of the property 'compilerOptions': object is null or undefined"

Some people have suggesting adding to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
...
  <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That's rejected too.  I can find no way to fix this.

Comment: Are you creating an ASP.NET 5 project? I believe `tsconfig.json` won't work with any other type of project.

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET 5 with latest version of Visual Studio 2015 Community.  Add existing item even offers tsconfig as a specific option with the default content I show.